# SSH: Clientalivemaxcount=0 with Putty?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, putty, winscp

So, I'm wondering about some specific behaviour of my SSH daemon when using Clientaliveinterval and Clientalivemaxcount.

Assume the following config:

`Clientaliveinterval 60
Clientalivemaxcount 0`

Also assume the following other parameters:

- Server OS: Debian Stretch-based (Proxmox VE 5)
- Client OS: Windows 10 64-bit
- Connecting with: WinSCP and Putty

The described settings above should disconnect my client after 60 seconds without sending packets.
Now, this works when it comes down to my WinSCP-session. But why does this not work for Putty?

EDIT: See my own answer on this for describing what was wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Do you happen to have Keep alives turned on, it's under 'connections' in putty?

Comment: Thanks, @djsmiley2k. I added an answer that describes what I did to fix that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment from [djsmiley2k](https://superuser.com/users/38001/djsmiley2k) that brought me to the right track!

I'ld like to explain what was wrong in my case (as it's not that obvious in the first place, I think), so it might help others.

1. After logging in I started a Putty session from inside WinSCP.
2. I waited the specified time and after 60 seconds the WinSCP-session got disconnected.
3. However, my Putty session was still working.
4. Right click on the Putty terminal window --> Change Settings --> Connection
5. I now noticed that there's a value of 30s set for `Seconds between keepalives`.
6. After manually setting this to 0, I got disconnected after the defined timeframe as expected.
7. However, when reconnecting the same behaviour occured again.

[From WinSCPs official documentation on that](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#session_configuration):

> By default, WinSCP creates temporary site settings for PuTTY (under the name >"WinSCP temporary session”). The site settings will contain only the options >known by WinSCP, mostly connection options. It will particularly lack any >terminal options, so the defaults will apply. To change the defaults, modify >the “Default Settings” profile in PuTTY.
>
> If you want to configure your own session-specific options, you can save PuTTY >site settings with the same name as a WinSCP site. WinSCP will then instruct >PuTTY to open that session (It will not export any settings, nor a connection >options).

To fix this behaviour:

1. Open Putty (outside of WinSCP).
2. Load the special session `WinSCP temporary session`
3. Go to `Connection`
4. Check that the `keepalives`-value is set to 0.
5. Go back to `Session`
6. Save the configuration under **the same name as your Session name in
   WinSCP**.
7. Now try again and you should find out both the WinSCP and the Putty connection are terminated as expected.